# Electric field intensity inside mixed dielectric capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, conductors

I have a capacitor with stacked dielectrics where $d_1 =10^{-3} \ m$ , $\varepsilon_{1} = 7$ and $d_2 =0.5 \cdot 10^{-3} \ m$ , $\varepsilon_{2} = 2$ and $V = 500V$. How would I go about calculating the electric field intensity in each dielectric?

I know that I can treat the capacitor as 2 capacitors connected in series. I can get $E = Vd$ and  $V = E_1d_1 + E_2d_2$ but I don't know how to get the actual values of $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: Your first guess is not right because $E$ is not the same in both dielectrics. What do you mean by $E$?

Comment: I worded that poorly. 
Voltage in a homogenous field is $V_{1,2} = E\cdot l$, so if I apply that to $V = V_1 + V_2$ I get $V =E_1d_1 + E_2d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

So you need another equation that relates $E_1$ and $E_2$. Hint: use the continuity of the displacement vector $D$ across the boundary between the two dielectrics.

Comment: Would it be $D = D_1 = D_2$ therefore $\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_rE_1 = \varepsilon_0\varepsilon_rE_2 \implies E_1 = \frac{\varepsilon_2E_2}{\varepsilon_1}$ 
so $V = \frac{\varepsilon_2E_2d_1}{\varepsilon_1} + E_2d_2 \implies E_2= \frac{\varepsilon_1V}{\varepsilon_2d_1+\varepsilon_1d_2}$ ?